# How to update multiple lines adding value in int column in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP application which needs to update multiple product rows. This update should add a given number to the current value of the column called estoque.

Example: add 3 units to product  A, 6 units to product B, etc.

Is there way to do this using only one query, like this?

```
insert into venda_produto (`cod`,`estoque`) 
    values (49477,`estoque`+3), (98798,`estoque`+6) 
    on duplicate key update `cod`=COALESCE( VALUES(`cod`), `cod`),`estoque`=COALESCE( VALUES(`estoque`), `estoque`)
```

`

Comment: So your key is `cod` and you want to increment `estoque`?

Comment: Do you know if the rows exist yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
INSERT INTO vendo_produto (cod, estoque)
VALUES (49477, 3), (98798, 6)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE estoque = estoque + VALUES(estoque);
```